# Merge sort 3 way java

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

I have to make a 3 way merge sort of an array. the array length is a in a power of 3, i.e. 3,9,27 etc. So I can use only one split function and not "left","mid","right".

Would like to get an answer how to repair it and why does not it work.
I have written the code, however don't know how to get it to work.

Here it is:
EDITED THE CODE, STILL DOES NOT WORK

```
public class Ex3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {        //main function
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);       //scanner 
     int size = in.nextInt();
     int[] arr = new int[size];
     for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
     }
     in.close();
     arr = merge3sort (arr);    //send to the function to merge
     for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){    //printer
            System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");
     }

}

static int[] split(int[] m, int thirdNum) { //split function that splits to 3 arrays
    int third[] = new int[m.length/3];
    int third1[]=new int[m.length/3];
    int third2[]=new int[m.length/3];
    for(int i = 0; i<=m.length/3; i++)
        third[i]=m[i];
    for(int i=0; i<=m.length/3;i++)
        third1[i]=m[i+thirdNum];
    for(int i=0; i<=m.length/3;i++)
        third2[i]=m[i+2*thirdNum];


    return merge(third,third1,third2);
    //return null;
}

static int minOf3(int[] a3) { //function that finds out how what is the index of the smallest number

    int num0 = a3[0];
    int num1 = a3[1];
    int num2 = a3[2];
    int idx = 0;
    if(num0<num1 && num1<num2)
        idx=0;
    if(num1<num0 && num0<num2)
        idx=1;
    else
        idx=2;
    return idx;
}

static int[] merge(int[] th0, int[] th1, int[] th2) { //function that sorts the numbers between 3 arrays
    int len0=th0.length;
    int len1=th1.length;
    int len2=th2.length;
    int[] united = new int[len0+len1+len2];
    int ind = 0; int i0=0; int i1=0; int i2=0;
    while(i0<len0 && i1<len1 && i2<len2){
        if(th0[i0]<th1[i1]){
            if(th0[i0]<th2[i2]){
                united[ind]=th0[i0];
                i0=i0+1;
            }//end inner if
            else{
                united[ind]=th2[i2];
                i2=i2+1;
            }//end inner else
            }//end outer if
        else{
            united[ind]=th1[i1];
            i1=i1+1;    
            }//end outer else
        ind=ind+1;
        }//end while
     for (int i = i0; i < len0; i = i + 1) {
          united[ind] = th0[i];
          ind = ind + 1;
        }
     for (int i = i1; i < len1; i = i + 1) {
          united[ind] = th1[i];
          ind = ind + 1;
        }for (int i = i2; i < len2; i = i + 1) {
              united[ind] = th2[i];
              ind = ind + 1;
            }

    return united;
}

static int[] merge3sort(int[] m) {  //function that glues all together

    if (m.length == 1) {
        return m;
    }
    else{

        return merge(merge3sort(split(m,m.length/3)),merge3sort(split(m,m.length/3)),merge3sort(split(m,m.length/3)));      }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at ololosh1.Ex3.split(Ex3.java:27)
    at ololosh1.Ex3.merge3sort(Ex3.java:98)
    at ololosh1.Ex3.main(Ex3.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=m.length/3; i++)
    third[i]=m[i];
for(int i=0; i<=m.length/3;i++)
    third1[i]=m[i+thirdNum];
for(int i=0; i<=m.length/3;i++)
    third2[i]=m[i+2*thirdNum];
```

Arrays are indexed from 0 to length-1. Each `third*` array has length `m.length/3`. Therefore their index can only go up to `m.length/3 - 1`. Yet you are indexing up to *and including* `m.length/3`.

Once you get your application working correctly, you really should clean it up. There is a lot of redundancy. For example, you are using the expression `m.length/3` multiple times in method `split()` but you are also passing that same value to it as an argument.

Comment: I understend your point but not how to repair it, how to exchange. can you please show me a repaired code part?

Comment: I  have changed the 'm.length/3 - 1' but dont get how to change the rest. Now I'm getting stuckoverflow at this row 'return merge(third,third1,third2);' and '   return merge(merge3sort(split(m,m.length/3)),merge3sort(split(m,m.length/3)),merge3sort(split(m,m.length/3)))'

Comment: I don't know how your code works (or how it's meant to work) - I just looked at a specific part that was giving you the exception. There are obviously other problems. For the stack overflow exception, look at the definition of merge3sort(). It is a recursive function, and its terminating condition is m.length == 1. However, if you trace where its argument comes from, you'll see that it always has the same length, which is never 1. Therefore it will never terminate (in practice the stack will overflow). You need to go through your code carefully and trace the data flow.